# Identity of custom expo client can’t be verified

Tags: react-native, expo

I have built a custom expo client for my iPhone, but when I try to install it on my iPhone I am getting the following error:

[image]

I already downloaded and installed all certificates from the developer Portal.

Any suggestions what could be wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found out, that there was a mismatch between the devices online and the device I'm using for development.

Cleaning things up and registering a new device via expo cli did the trick